# Insert Javascript on every page of the site(s)

Tags: javascript

I have a group of sites. All of them are built in old technologies. Each HTML site is made up of a bunch of HTML pages with JavaScript in them. The sites do not have any master page/layout. I want to insert a common script something like Google Analytics script on each page of each site. Only the value of one identifier will change, one identifier for each site. I do not want to go to each HTML and insert JavaScript code in it. Is there any other solution available to achieve this?

Comment: Not really, the best would be -> Place your code inside another JS file and then include in each page.  In theory you could intercept the HTML pages at the backend if say you was using Node / PHP etc, it could just then intercept HTML pages and inject it.  But it's not a trivial task.

Comment: You can use bulk replace tools for edditing multiple files at once. Depending on your OS it can be gerp/sed for Linux or some GUI based stuff for Windows. Which OS are you using?

Comment: short answer is no. The best thing would be to place this extra code in a .js file and then just add a `<script` tag to each page, so that it loads that script file into the page. Then it's just a (tedious) copy/paste job. If the HTML in all the pages has some structure in common then, to relieve the tedium, you might be able to write a shell script using grep or something to inject the tag automatically into the same spot in each file.

Comment: As @Volodymyr said, search and replace is the simplest way.  2 things to consider - 1. make it a generic script that you can modify in the future, should you ever want to add or modify anything site-wide again and 2. make sure you start the script path with a `/` so the Url is absolute to the domain name, or you'll end up with files in subfolders returning a 404 error.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I will create a separate .js file and write a shell script to insert the script tag in every HTML. Thanks!